# Undefined index notice

Tags: php

I have spent days trying to figure this out to no avail.  I have checked the PHP docs as well as multiple other form questions regarding the "undefined index" notice and what seems to be the usual solution "isset()" function.

But I cannot work out the solution in my case.

Here is the code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<!-- Here are all the form fields -->
<input type="submit" name="send" value="send"/>
</form>

<?php

            $con = mysql_connect("#","#","#");
            if (!$con)
            {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            mysql_select_db("#", $con);

            $sql="
            INSERT INTO events (e_date, e_time, e_type, e_name)
            VALUES ('$_POST[form_e_date]','$_POST[form_e_time]','$_POST[form_e_type]','$_POST[form_e_name]')";

            if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            echo "1 record added";

            mysql_close($con)

        ?>
```

The 4 notices occur on the line with the $sql variable starting at "VALUES" and refer to the form_e_date, etc.

I apologize for asking a question that I realize gets somewhat frequently, but I have tried other people's solutions which either do no work for me or else I am not implementing them correctly.

Please help, and please feel free to leave any other constructive feedback about my code as I'm a newbie.

Thanks!

Comment: what are the notices and errors  paste them in your question

Comment: $_POST[form_e_time] should be $_POST['form_e_time'] unless form_e_time is defined as a constant, likewise any other associative array index you reference, whether your own arrays or the superglobals.... this question is answered dozens of times each week

Comment: but do note that `insert`ing directly from user inputs is **very** dangerous and all user inputs should be escaped before use in database statements of any kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

```
'$_POST[form_e_date]','$_POST[form_e_time]','$_POST[form_e_type]','$_POST[form_e_name]'
```

you should NOT use

```
'$_POST["form_e_date"]','$_POST["form_e_time"]','$_POST["form_e_type"]','$_POST["form_e_name"]'
```

because of the danger of SQL injection attacks.

you should be using `mysql_real_escape_string` to protect yourself against this.

this would be much safer:

```
if (array_key_exists("form_e_date", $_POST))
  $form_e_date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["form_e_date"]);
else
  $form_e_date = null;

if (array_key_exists("form_e_time", $_POST))
  $form_e_time = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["form_e_time"]);
else
  $form_e_time = null;

if (array_key_exists("form_e_type", $_POST))
  $form_e_type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["form_e_type"]);
else
  $form_e_type = null;

if (array_key_exists("form_e_name", $_POST))
  $form_e_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["form_e_name"]);
else
  $form_e_name = null;
.
.
.
$sql = "INSERT INTO events (e_date, e_time, e_type, e_name) " . 
  "VALUES ('{$form_e_date}','{$form_e_time}','{$form_e_type}','{$form_e_name}')";
```

Comment: Thanks dldnh, I had actually read about not allowing user input directly into database and was going to address that later; the application I'm working on is currently just for my own personal use offline until I know what I'm doing (I had seen somewhere about the mysql_real_escape_string function as well)  ;) But I did try your solution to my notices problem, but now I"m getting the undefined index notices on the the 4 lines $form_e_date, etc.  Obviously I'm still doing something wrong and/or putting code in the wrong place?

Comment: just wanted to make sure you knew about that.

Comment: dldnh, I implemented your code and it took the 4 notices off the affected 1 line from before, but now the 4 notices are on the 4 lines you gave me.

Comment: hope the edit I just made fixes them... if an array doesn't contain the named keys, you get errors, and I'm assuming those are the ones you mean.

Comment: if that _doesn't_ fix it, on the other hand, just paste in whatever the error says

Comment: Your updated code fixed the notices!  Thanks so much for taking the time to help me with this, I really appreciate it.  Now I'll go through your code so I understand the pieces and new (to me) functions.  Thanks again.